# Use mongo-style syntax to query in-memory JavaScript objects from arrays instead of Mongo collections?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

In mongo I can construct a query like below to return objects with height not equal to 4 from a collection.

```
var mongoQuery = { height: { "$ne": 4 } };
```

But say I have an in-memory array of objects and want to query from them the same way:

```
var myArr = [{height: 5}, {height: 4}, {height:3}]
```

Are there any existing libraries or ways for me to use similar syntax on arrays instead of mongo collections? E.g.:

```
var result = someUtil(myArr, {height: {"$ne": 4}});  //returns all objects with height != 4
```

EDIT: I don't want to do `!= 4`, but rather generally translate from any Mongo operator (e.g. `$eq`, `$ge`, etc.)

Comment: In other words, you want to use mongo-style syntax to validate JS objects in memory instead of from the mongo API?

Comment: Yep. That's exactly what I want to do.

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you want, but you could use the filter function to do that:

var filtered = myArr.filter(function(x) { return x.height != 4; });

Answer (score 9):

Please take a look at [sift.js](https://github.com/crcn/sift.js). That is what you want. But use it if you really need mongodb like queries, otherwise use another library like [lodash](https://lodash.com/) or underscore.

Answer (score 2):

Here're your options:

- [minimongo](https://github.com/mWater/minimongo) - An NPM fork of Meteor.js minimongo
- [nedb](https://github.com/seald/nedb) - Embedded persistent or in memory database for Node.js, Electron and browsers, 100% JavaScript, no binary dependency
- [sift.js](https://github.com/crcn/sift.js) - Mongodb queries in JavaScript
- [mingo](https://github.com/kofrasa/mingo) - MongoDB query language for in-memory objects

Every library has its own pros/cons compared to other libs like indexing or aggregation so you need to research your options and figure out your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#) library.

`var result = _.find(myArr, function(item){ return item.height == 4 });`

Comment: I don't want to do just `item.height == 4` though, but I'm looking for something to convert the Mongo `$ne1`

Comment: You can use variables,  item[fieldname]  == value

Comment: It's no reponding to the question.